# Mass Image Change - Magento

Tags: magento

Is there anyway to change all images of products in a single category ?

I have a category with products that have no images, about 175 of them, and I wish to use the same image for all of them.

Is this possible without going in manually and doing this ?

Thanks !

Comment: You could try using Magmi and import a set of updates with the new image. Alternatively, and a bit of a "hacky" way, might be to set a default image in configuration>catalog>Product Image Placeholders. But remember this will be the default image for all products without an image.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Magento's admin interface is not very advanced, and does not provide any automated way of assigning the same image to multiple products (other than going into each product one by one, of course).

The most straight forward way to solve this is through a small script:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(123);

$products = $category->getProductCollection();

foreach ($products as $product)
{
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery(
        Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'images' . DS . 'image.jpg',
        /* attribute */ 'image',
        /* move */ false,
        /* exclude */ false
    );
}
```

Code is untested, but that's the general idea - grab the list of products, go through each one, and use `addImageToMediaGallery()` to add the image to the product.

This type of script can be easily implemented as a shell script (see scripts in the `shell` directory).